# Differences/similarities between llvm::DenseMap and std::map

Tags: c++, stl, llvm

Recently I came across DenseMap data structure which is widely used in llvm. I think it is some sort of optimized version of `std::map(?)`. Could anyone help me understand the difference or similarities between them?

Comment: Good explanation here: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#map-like-containers-std-map-densemap-etc

Comment: thanks @RichardCritten

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`llvm::DenseMap` is a replacement for `std::unordered_map`, so it's not quite meant to replace `std::map` (at least not if you've carefully chosen based on the ordered vs. unordered properties).

Unlike `std::unordered_map`, `std::map` guarantees that the iteration order of the container matches the order defined by your comparator (by default, `std::less`). In many cases, you don't care about iteration order... but in the few cases where it matters, `DenseMap` isn't an option.

Now, to contrast `DenseMap` with `std::unordered_map`: unlike the `std` container, `DenseMap` keeps all its data in one memory allocation, and it does away with buckets in favor of keeping keys and values next to each other in memory. Both these features are a big win for [data locality](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html) and thus speed in nearly all contexts.

In addition, `DenseMap` allocates a large number of key/value pairs by default (64, in fact), so at small sizes, insertions are nearly free. The downside of that, of course, is that it’s memory inefficient if you’re creating a lot of very small maps, or if your types themselves are large; if your container will never grow to 64 elements, you're wasting memory. That may or may not actually hurt you depending on your use case.

One final difference compared to `std::unordered_map` can catch some people off guard: a `DenseMap`'s iterators are invalidated after *every* insertion (unlike `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, where the iterators are only invalidated if a cache rehashing occurs). This strikes me as mostly a theoretical problem, since you could of course just store the keys rather than iterators. (And unlike with vectors, it's rather uncommon to find real code that retains map iterators.)

I've put together some [benchmarks](https://tylerayoung.com/2019/01/29/benchmarks-of-cache-friendly-data-structures-in-c/) comparing `DenseMap` to the `std` containers, as well as [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/s3cur3/llvm-data-structure-benchmarks) if you'd like to run the benchmarks on your own machine. Four selected graphs are below, showing insertion and random lookup speeds for maps at various sizes.

**Insertion speeds in small maps**

[image: Insertion speeds in small maps]

**Insertion speeds in large maps**

[image: Insertion speeds in large maps]

**Random lookups in small maps**
[image: Random lookups in small maps]

**Random lookups in large maps**
[image: Random lookups in large maps]

Comment: `std::map` doesn't guarantee that the iteration order matches the insertion order. Rather, the order is determined by the compare function you specify as a template parameter, which defaults to `std::less<Key>`.